# Cant change Ubuntu theme from Lockscreen ,Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome, themes

Once I changed the theme of my Ubuntu 18.04 from the lock screen using the logo near the password field. I chose *Ubuntu with Wayland*.

Before the desktop was this:

[image: Desktop before change]

Later it was like this:

[image: Desktop after change]

I lost the drop-down applications menu and the top panel.
When I tried to repeat my first step from lock-screen by logout it failed.

I want to have my desktop the way it was before. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably talking about GNOME Flashback session, which is installable by

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-panel
```

then reboot and choose this session on login screen.

But its functionality is limited. So the better way is to install Ubuntu MATE desktop by `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mate-desktop^` and use it as daily driver.

Comment: Thanks bro it worked